# Configuration of requirejs and shim

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, shim

I have this kind of config:

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        jquery: '../libs/jquery/dist/jquery',
        uicore: '../libs/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.core',
        uiwidget: '../libs/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.widget',
        uidialog: '../libs/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.dialog'
    },

    shim: {
        uicore: ['jquery'],
        uiwidget: ['uicore'],
        uidialog: ['uiwidget']
    },

    urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime()

});

require(['uidialog'], function (d) {
    console.log(d); // undefined;
});
```

So, what is wrong with my code? Why does d is undefined? Every file has been downloaded, version of jquery is 2.1.

Please, help :(

Comment: I think that you need to set dependency on JQuery lib. See deps attribute (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Comment: why don't you combine core, widget, dialog into a single jquery.ui.custom.js file ??? Instead of putting them into separate files ???

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [Requirejs-getStarted](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html):

> Inside of main.js, you can use require() to load any other scripts you
>   need to run. This ensures a single entry point, since the data-main
>   script you specify is loaded asynchronously.
>
> require(["helper/util"], function(util) {
>       //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
>       //If util.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
>       //util's dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
>       //the module value for "helper/util". });

I suggest, for instance:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.9.0'
    }
});
```

Then:

```
require(['jquery'], function( jq ) {
    console.log( jq ) // OK
});
```

Probably you have wrong path in your configuration..

## edit

Have you try:

```
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response! jQuery is loaded, there is nothing wrong with it. The problem is with jquery plugins. For instance, UI or fancybox. If there is no `define` function in code, then it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: is to export `$`. Like this:

```
'ui.core': {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    exports: '$'
},
'ui.widget': {
    deps: ['ui.core'],
    exports: '$'
},
'ui.button': {
    deps: ['ui.core'],
    exports: '$'
},
'ui.dialog': {
    deps: ['ui.widget', 'ui.button'],
    exports: '$'
}
```